# C++, как работает RTTI

Tags: c++, rtti, dynamic-cast

Я бы хотел понять, как в `C++` работает `RTTI`.

Мне понятно, как вызываются виртуальные методы. Это происходит через таблицу виртуальных методов, указатель на эту таблицу размещается в объекте каждого класса, который содержит виртуальные методы. У каждого класса с виртуальными методами есть своя таблица виртуальных методов.

Но мне не совсем понятно, как во время исполнения определяется тип объекта. В объектах размещается какая-то дополнительная информация? Например, `ID` типа.

И как следствие, я не понимаю, велико ли отличие между ручным приведением типов при помощи `dynamic_cast` и использованием паттерна `visitor` для реализации двойной диспетчеризации.

Comment: В разных компиляторах может быть сделано по-разному. Вот, к примеру, [небольшая заметка](https://blog.quarkslab.com/visual-c-rtti-inspection.html) по RTTI в какой-то из версий студии.

Comment: *"использованием паттерна visitor для реализации двойной диспетчеризации"* Можно пример, как это выглядит?

Comment: Stroustrup - Fast dynamic casting - http://www.stroustrup.com/fast_dynamic_casting.pdf и еще пример реализации в gcc: 
http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1790322.html

Comment: Изгоняем иуду из нашего города! - Крики из страны C++. Он спрашивает как всё устроено! - Трогает святое! Позор! И программист уходит плача и говорит: я всего-лишь вызвал функции из массива виртуальных функций. Сам написал... И так он стал Сишником....

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, http://cpp-reference.ru/patterns/behavioral-patterns/visitor/